# HTML and CSS responsiveness

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend, web-deployment

I have been trying to solve this issue but for some reason my code is wrong and I am a beginner, I am trying to get those in place, but it isn't responsive, and they get distorted. I am seeking some help to solve this.

please do look at the link(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO5F2.jpg) above.

Thank you!!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alice&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alice&family=NTR&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

navup{
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 62px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;   
}

navup h1{
    /*padding-left: 40rem;*/
    font-family: 'alice', serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

navup li{
    list-style: none;
}

navup ul li{
    display: flex;
}

navup li a{
    /*padding-right: -10rem;*/
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'NTR', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

navup img{
    /*margin-right: 200px;*/
}

navlo{
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    max-height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF,#898989); 
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 9px;
}

navlo img{
    width: 61px;
    height: 61px;
    margin-top: 2.95px;
}

navlo ul{
    display: flex;
}

navlo ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0rem 1.5rem;
}

navlo li a{
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'NTR', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.barone img{
    position: absolute;
width: 89px;
height: 10px;
left: 906px;
top: 46px;

background: #001E5A;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.bartwo img{
    position: absolute;
width: 102px;
height: 10px;
left: 1025px;
top: 46px;

background: #001E5A;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.barthree img{
    position: absolute;
width: 109px;
height: 10px;
left: 1157px;
top: 46px;

background: #001E5A;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.barfour img{
    /* Services bar */


position: absolute;
width: 89px;
height: 10px;
left: 1296px;
top: 46px;

background: #001E5A;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.barfive img{
    /* Partners Bar */


position: absolute;
width: 101px;
height: 10px;
left: 1415px;
top: 46px;

background: #001E5A;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.barsix img{
position: absolute;
width: 111px;
height: 11px;
left: 1546px;
top: 46px;

background: #001E5A;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.bars img{
    display: inline;
    /*width: 50%;*/
    margin-top: 70px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Art</title>
    <style>
        /* width */
            ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                background-color: grey;
                width: 13px;
            }

        /* Track */
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
                box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
 
        /* Handle */
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
                background: black; 
                border-radius: 10px;
            }

        /* Handle on hover */
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
                background: black; 
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <SECTION>
        <navup>
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Art</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Login/Signup</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="../images/account.png"></a>
                </li>
            </ul> -->
        </navup>
    </SECTION>
    <section>
        <navlo>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="../html/index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">ABOUT ME</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">BUY ART</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">BLOG</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">PARTNERED</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">CONTACT ME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </navlo>
        <section class="bars">
                <div class="barone"><img src="../images/homebar.svg" alt="a lower bar for home"></div>
                <div class="bartwo"><img src="../images/aboutmebar.svg" alt="a lower bar for home"></div>
                <div class="barthree"><img src="../images/buyartbar.svg" alt="a lower bar for home"></div>
                <div class="barfour"><img src="../images/blogbar.svg" alt="a lower bar for home"></div>
                <div class="barfive"><img src="../images/partnersbar.svg" alt="a lower bar for home"></div>
                <div class="barsix"><img src="../images/contactmebar.svg" alt="a lower bar for home"></div>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Rajayogi Nandina

Comment: I ran the above on JSFiddle and it works fine, You can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ky82zgsL/).

Comment: It isn’t responsive, I want the blue lines to be under the links/clickable.

Comment: why can't use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: I tried using the @media screen and(max-width); thing but the problem is it works for that particular screen but when I try zooming in or out then again it gets distorted making it awful.